# Mysql query to join condition not working

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a case where I need to get data by joining `table_1`, `table_2`, `table_3`, `table_6`below is the query representing all conditions that I need to put below query works good and get perfect data

> Query 1

```
SELECT   table_1.id                                                   
AS id1,   table_1.deal_id                                             
AS deal_id5,   CONVERT_TZ(table_1.due_date, 'UTC', 'EST')             
AS sclr20,   table_2.deal_name                                        
AS deal_name22 FROM  table_1   INNER JOIN  table_2 ON (table_1.deal_id
= table_2.deal_id)   INNER JOIN  table_3 ON (table_1.id = table_3.child_bwic_id)   INNER JOIN  table_6 ON (table_6.id =
table_3.bwic_id)

WHERE table_6.data_source_id <> 2
      AND table_1.status IN (1, 2, 3)
      AND DATE(table_1.due_date) = '2015-08-13'

GROUP BY table_1.deal_id, sclr20 ORDER BY sclr20 ASC, id1 ASC;
```

Now due to some requirement I need to add one more table to condition, `table_4`, and check if record is there in `table_4` then flag it so I wrote query to left join `table_4` as:

> Query 2

```
SELECT   table_1.id                                                   
AS id1,   table_1.deal_id                                             
AS deal_id5,   CONVERT_TZ(table_1.due_date, 'UTC', 'EST')             
AS sclr20,   table_2.deal_name                                        
AS deal_name22,   if(table_4.id IS NULL, 'public', 'private')         
AS sclr51

FROM child_bwic table_1   INNER JOIN deal table_2 ON (table_1.deal_id
= table_2.deal_id)   INNER JOIN bwic_child_association table_3 ON (table_1.id = table_3.child_bwic_id)   INNER JOIN bwic table_6 ON
(table_6.id = table_3.bwic_id)

  LEFT JOIN bwic_private_group_association table_4 ON table_6.id =
table_4.bwic_id

WHERE table_6.data_source_id <> 2
      AND table_1.status IN (1, 2, 3)
      AND DATE(table_1.due_date) = '2015-08-13'

GROUP BY table_1.deal_id, sclr20 ORDER BY sclr20 ASC, id1 ASC;
```

This one also works good and gives correct result set

To further drill down results I need to join `table_4` with `table_5` so that I can restrict results to a particular user's group. So I wrote query as:

> Query 3

```
SELECT

  table_1.id                                                          
AS id1,   table_1.deal_id                                             
AS deal_id5,   CONVERT_TZ(table_1.due_date, 'UTC', 'EST')             
AS sclr20,   table_2.deal_name                                        
AS deal_name22,   if(table_4.id IS NULL, 'public', 'private')         
AS sclr51 FROM child_bwic table_1   INNER JOIN deal table_2 ON
(table_1.deal_id = table_2.deal_id)   INNER JOIN
bwic_child_association table_3 ON (table_1.id = table_3.child_bwic_id)
INNER JOIN bwic table_6 ON (table_6.id = table_3.bwic_id)


  LEFT JOIN bwic_private_group_association table_4 ON table_6.id =
table_4.bwic_id   JOIN bwic_private_group_user_association table_5 ON
table_4.group_id = table_5.group_id AND table_5.user_id = 1512

WHERE table_6.data_source_id <> 2
      AND table_1.status IN (1, 2, 3)
      AND DATE(table_1.due_date) = '2015-08-13'

GROUP BY table_1.deal_id, sclr20 ORDER BY sclr20 ASC, id1 ASC;
```

but this query is not returing results if a record is not present in `table_4` (public records) which I was getting in case of Query 2.

I short I wan't to left join results of query 1 with inner join of `table_4` and `table_5`.

Any help would be appreciated.

> Edit:

Also forgot to mention that I am using Doctrine Query Builder. So I do not have option of subqueries. I have simplified this query to avoid showing Doctrine QB implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but this should work, not tested.

```
SELECT

  table_1.id
    AS id1,
  table_1.deal_id
    AS deal_id5,
  CONVERT_TZ(table_1.due_date, 'UTC', 'EST')
    AS sclr20,
  table_2.deal_name
    AS deal_name22,
  if(table_4.id IS NULL, 'public', 'private')
    AS sclr51
FROM child_bwic table_1
  INNER JOIN deal table_2 ON (table_1.deal_id = table_2.deal_id)
  INNER JOIN bwic_child_association table_3 ON (table_1.id = table_3.child_bwic_id)
  INNER JOIN bwic table_6 ON (table_6.id = table_3.bwic_id)


  LEFT JOIN bwic_private_group_association table_4 ON table_6.id = table_4.bwic_id
  left JOIN bwic_private_group_user_association table_5 ON table_4.group_id = table_5.group_id

WHERE table_6.data_source_id <> 2
      AND table_1.status IN (1, 2, 3)
      AND DATE(table_1.due_date) >= '2015-08-19'
      and (table_5.user_id = 1512 or table_5.user_id is NULL )
GROUP BY table_1.deal_id, sclr20
ORDER BY sclr20 ASC, id1 ASC;
```

what I did is I left joined `table_5` keeping condition `table_5.user_id = 1512 or table_5.user_id is NULL` so that you will get only user 1512 data along with data not in table5 and table4.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create an inline view which joins tables 4 & 5 first then joins back to your base set...  I did this aliasing the results as "B" then updated the outer select to use B.ID and updated the on criteria to `ON table_6.id = B.bwic_id` for the left join

Why this works is that the engine must first resolve the sub select generating the results before the left join occurs.  With the approach you have the left join is getting negated due to the inner join after the left join.

in MsACCESS ()'s can be added around the joins to indicate order of join operation.  mySQL may support this as well, I've just not used it.

Ideally you would replace the * with the field list your interested in for tables 4 & 5.  This would be REQUIRED if tables 4 & 5 both have and ID field as referenced in the outer select.

```
SELECT
  table_1.id AS id1,   
  table_1.deal_id AS deal_id5,   
  CONVERT_TZ(table_1.due_date, 'UTC', 'EST') AS sclr20,   
  table_2.deal_name AS deal_name22,   
  if(B.id IS NULL, 'public', 'private') AS sclr51 

FROM child_bwic table_1   
INNER JOIN deal table_2 
 ON table_1.deal_id = table_2.deal_id
INNER JOIN bwic_child_association table_3 
  ON table_1.id = table_3.child_bwic_id
INNER JOIN bwic table_6 
  ON (table_6.id = table_3.bwic_id)
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT * 
  FROM bwic_private_group_association table_4 
  INNER JOIN bwic_private_group_user_association table_5 
    ON table_4.group_id = table_5.group_id 
   AND table_5.user_id = 1512) B
  ON table_6.id = B.bwic_id   

WHERE table_6.data_source_id <> 2
      AND table_1.status IN (1, 2, 3)
      AND DATE(table_1.due_date) = '2015-08-13'
GROUP BY table_1.deal_id, sclr20 ORDER BY sclr20 ASC, id1 ASC;
```